# Magento 2 Customer Data Requisition List Empty List After Login

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

During my testing of the requisition list button on my orders view. I noticed that the existing requisition list I have created does not show after I log in and only shows after I add an additional requisition list. I have tried the customer data subscribe but seems to be not working.

Comment: Is it your customization? Your issue may relate to the cache. The best way is to debug your feature.